# How do I make the navigation bar stop disappearing when clicking on anchor links within? Why is it doing that?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, dom-events, navigationbar

I'm having a bit of a UI problem here. I have a nav bar that fades in and out on scroll up or scroll down. The problem is that when you click on links in the nav, the nav bar completely disappears when clicking on text that's to the right of each other. I've tried removing event listeners, nesting event listeners and removing from within the nested one, making the event a separate function and cancelling it out, making the scroll event true and false/null, etc, all to no avail.

How can I get the nav bar to stay and not disappear on click events? Any answers, suggestions, improvements or some hints in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, been stuck at this for quite awhile now.

CODE:

```
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="portfolio.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      font: 24px 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      background: url("images/someTree.jpg") no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }

    header {
      opacity: 0.9;
      width: 100%;
      height: 85px;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1000;
      background-color: #96C339;
    }

    header h1#logo {
      float: left;
      font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
      font-size: 40px;
      color: #FFF;
      font-weight: 400;
      margin-left: 35px;
    }

    header nav {
      display: inline-block;
      float: right;
    }

    header nav a {
      line-height: 100px;
      margin-left: 20px;
      margin-right: 20px;
      color: #FFF;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    a {
      font-family: 'Droid Sans', serif;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      line-height: 40px;
    }

    .active {
      font-family: 'Droid Sans', serif;
      font-size: 22px;
      color: #000;
      text-decoration: none;
      line-height: 40px;
    }

    #about {
      background-color: #fff;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      opacity: 0.6;
    }

    #skills {
      background-color: #fff;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      opacity: 0.6;
    }

    #contact {
      background-color: #fff;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      opacity: 0.6;
    }

    @media all and (max-width: 770px) {
      header h1#logo {
        font-size: 30px;
        display: block;
        float: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 100px;
        line-height: 55px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      header nav {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: -65px;
      }

      header nav a {
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 50px;
        margin: 0 5px;
      }
    }
  </style>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header class="nav">
      <h1 id="logo">DMac</h1>
      <nav>
        <a href="#about" class="active">About</a>
        <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="about" class="section"></div>
    <div id="skills" class="section"></div>
    <div id="contact" class="section"></div>
    <script> (function () {
      
        // Where Navigation text links to
        const section = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
        // Navigation bar wrapper
        const nav = document.querySelector(".nav");
        // Navigation anchor text
        const anchors = document.querySelectorAll(".visible");
      
        // Set
        const sections = {};
      
        'use strict';
        // Initial scroll state
        let scrollPos = 0;
        // Scroll event
        let scrolling = false;
        document.addEventListener('scroll', scrollEvent)
        // Detects scroll state and compares it with the new one to fade in/fade out.
        function scrollEvent() {
          scrolling = true;
          if ((document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top > scrollPos) {
            nav.style.transition = "all 1.0s";
            nav.style.opacity = 1;
            nav.style.visibility = "visible"
          } else {
            nav.style.transition = "all 1.0s";
            nav.style.opacity = 0;
            nav.style.visibility = "hidden";
          }
          scrollPos = (document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top;
      
      
          // Turn each dom anchor into and array and iterate through each (by id)
          const arr = Array.from(section)
          arr.forEach(function (el) {
            sections[el.id] = el.offsetTop;
          });
      
          const scrollPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
          Object.keys(sections).forEach((el) => {
            if (sections[el] <= scrollPosition) {
              document.querySelector('.active').setAttribute('class', ' ');
              document.querySelector('a[href*=' + el + ']').setAttribute('class', 'active');
            }
          })
        }
      
        // Keep the scroll function from constantly firing. 
        setInterval(function () {
          if (scrolling) {
            scrolling = false;
          }
        }, 250);
      
        // Start scroll event
        scrollEvent();
      
      }());
      </script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you scroll following code hides the scrollbar. Click on nav link also scrolls to some section on your page. Once you reach the section you should make the scrollbar visible again.

```
         if ((document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top > scrollPos) {
            nav.style.transition = "all 1.0s";
            nav.style.opacity = 1;
            nav.style.visibility = "visible"
          } else {
            nav.style.transition = "all 1.0s";
            nav.style.opacity = 0;
            nav.style.visibility = "hidden";
          }
```

I updated the following to your code and it worked.

```
       setInterval(function () {
          if (scrolling) {
            scrolling = false;
            nav.style.transition = "all 1.0s";
            nav.style.opacity = 1;
            nav.style.visibility = "visible"
          }
        }, 250);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. Makes sense now that you mention it since setInterval is constantly firing. Didn't realize that's what was tripping things up.

Comment: I'll accepted this before I noticed a bug.  When a user pauses for a second, the nav bar will come back up again - that's not what I wanted to happen. I realized it was working before I put the setInterval in earlier today. I just took out all of the setInterval and the explicit true false logic and it works as it did earlier, ty

Comment: @dannymac yes code had a lot of logic that can be optimized. I just took a look at the issue you mentioned and fixed without making any other change.